# React - Filtering returns wrong rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

It's driving me crazy. I've created a list with several entries. I added a filtering function, which seems to work fine. I've checked the number of results returned, but somehow it just showing the result number beginning at the first row.

For explanation:

Let's assume I search for "Zonen" and my filter function returns 4 rows with ID 23, 25, 59 and 60, the rows with ID's 1,2,3 and 4 are displayed. What I'm doing wrong!?

```
...    
render() {
let filteredList = this.state.freights.filter((freight) => {
    let search = this.state.search.toLowerCase();
    var values = Object.keys(freight).map(function(itm) { return freight[itm]; });
    var flag = false;

    values.forEach((val) => {
        if(val != undefined && typeof val === 'object') {
            var objval = Object.keys(val).map(function(objitm) { return val[objitm]; });
            objval.forEach((objvalue) => {
                if(objvalue != undefined && objvalue.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1) {
                    flag = true;
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            if(val != undefined && val.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1) {
                flag = true;
                return;
            }   
        }
    });
    if(flag) 
        return freight;
});
...
<tbody>
{
    filteredList.map((freight)=> {
      return (
        <Freight freight={freight} onClick={this.handleFreightClick.bind(this)} key={freight.id} />
      );
    })
}
</tbody>
...
```

**UPDATE**

`freights` is loaded and filled via AJAX JSON result. One object of `freights` looks like this:

[image]

I have a textbox where a user can perform a search. This search should return all `freight` objects which properties contain the search string.

The `filter` is so complex, because I want to also to search in sub-objects of freight. Maybe there is a more simple way?

"Zones" was just an example for a search string the user can search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution why the "wrong" freight entries are displayed.
I needed to add in `freight` component the `componentWillReceiveProps` method:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.freight) {
        this.setState({
            freight: nextProps.freight
        });
    }

}
```

Then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Now that your intentions are clearer, I suggest this much less complex solution.

First, you can write a recursive utility fn to get all values of all keys in an n-depth object. Like this, for example (I'm using lodash's utility fn `isObject` there):

```
const getAllValues = (obj) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(a, b) {
    const keyValue = obj[b];
    if (_.isObject(keyValue)){
      return a.concat(getAllValues(keyValue));
    } else {
      return a.concat(keyValue);
    }
  }, []);
}
```

Now that you have an array of all object's values, it makes your `filter` very simple:

```
let filteredList = this.state.freights.filter((freightItem) => {
   const allItemValues = getAllValues(freightItem);
   return allItemValues.includes(this.state.search);
});
```

That should be it. If something is not working, gimme a shout.

Comment: Please see my update in original post. Is there still something unclear?

Comment: Updated my answer. Check it out and provide feedback :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but now it's giving me the error 'too much recursion'. I need to check, if maybe there is a infinity loop.

Comment: how big is your array of freights?

Comment: there are 539 freight entries, each with 30 properties and until 12 sub-objects. could it be too much?

Comment: Yeah, that's way too much. You need to limit your array to chunks of 50 or 100 for better performance. You could run your filtering on those chunks, then. Or perhaps there's a way to optimize the input so you don't need all the values of an object?